# get_current_language_bidi not working as expected

Tags: python, django, internationalization

I have added `django.template.context_processors.i18n` to context_processors,
I have added `django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware` to middleware_classes, and I'm nearly certain this is unrelated, but just in case I also added `url(r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n'))` to urlpatterns.

I created a .po file successfully, compiled a .mo file, and the translations (where there are strings to be translated) are loading fine.

However, when I run the following code:

```
{% extends "page.html" %}
{% load i18n %}
{% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}
{% get_current_language_bidi as LANGUAGE_BIDI %}
{% block title %}{% trans "translation test" %}{% endblock %}
{% block page_main_content %}
<div id="some-text">
  <ul>
      <li>The current language is <b>{{ LANGUAGE_CODE }}</b></li>
      {% if LANGUAGE_BIDI %}
        <li>The current language is bidirectional</li>
      {% else %}
        <li>The current language is <b>not</b> bidirectional</li>
      {% endif %}
  </ul>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

What I get is:

> - The current language is he_IL
> - The current language is **not**    bidirectional

I would assume I'm importing something incorrectly or have misconfigured settings, but `get_current_language` is (clearly) working fine. So why is django incorrectly returning False for `get_current_language_bidi`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is something wrong with the source of your language preference. According to [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/i18n/#term-language-code), the expected separator is a dash. So Django may think that `he_IL` is a unknown language, and as such flags it not bidirectional by default.

You should [find out where this locale comes from](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-language-preference), and make sure it gives `he-il` or `he` instead of `he_IL`.